# Django calculating field depending on selection with manytomany field

Tags: python, django, signals, manytomanyfield

I am writing a web application using django rest.

I have a problem that i am struggling with for a few days now.

So i created a payroll model that calculates the gross value based on the number of hours worked and hourly rate by the employee and its working perfectly.

The main problem is that i want to calculate net value based on taxes and fixed costs (which are seperated models) choosen by user. Actually i made function that use post_save signal and it works, but i have to save object twice to calculate it correctly because if i save for the first time it sees old selections (i think its happening because function is called too fast and there is no time to create a relation between models).Earlier i used the function with m2mchanged signal, but there was a lot of code and if statements besides it didnt work well.

Models:

```
PERCENTAGE_VALIDATOR = [MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)]


class Taxes(models.Model):
    tax_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tax_percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, validators=PERCENTAGE_VALIDATOR)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tax'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Taxes'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.tax_name} - {self.tax_percentage}%'

class FixedCosts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Fixed Cost'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Fixed Costs'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.value}eur'
class Payroll(models.Model):
    payroll_for_user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payroll_month = models.DateField()
    payroll_hourly_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    payroll_net_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True) #net_value = gross_value - taxes
    payroll_gross_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    payroll_amount_of_hours_worked = models.IntegerField()
    payroll_taxes = models.ManyToManyField(Taxes, blank=True, related_name="payroll_taxes")
    payroll_fixed_costs = models.ManyToManyField(FixedCosts, blank=True, related_name="payroll_fixed_costs")
    payroll_send = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    payroll_send_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.payroll_for_user)

    def get_gross_value_based_on_hours(self):
        gross_value = int(self.payroll_hourly_rate * self.payroll_amount_of_hours_worked)
        return gross_value

    def get_hourly_rate(self):
        hourly_rate = self.payroll_for_user.hourly_rate
        return hourly_rate

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.payroll_hourly_rate:
            self.payroll_hourly_rate = self.get_hourly_rate()

        if not self.payroll_gross_value:
            self.payroll_gross_value = self.get_gross_value_based_on_hours()

        if not self.payroll_net_value:
            self.payroll_net_value = self.get_gross_value_based_on_hours()

        super(Payroll, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Signal function

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Payroll)
def get_net_value(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    gross_value = instance.payroll_gross_value
    payroll = Payroll.objects.filter(id=instance.id)
    net_value = False
    if instance.payroll_taxes.all().count() > 0:
        selected_taxes = instance.payroll_taxes.all().aggregate(Sum('tax_percentage'))
        total_taxes = selected_taxes['tax_percentage__sum'] / 100
        gross_value = gross_value - (gross_value * total_taxes)

    if instance.payroll_fixed_costs.all().count() > 0:
        fixed_costs = instance.payroll_fixed_costs.all().aggregate(Sum('value'))
        total_fixed_cost = fixed_costs['value__sum']
        net_value = gross_value - total_fixed_cost

    if net_value:
        payroll.update(payroll_net_value=net_value)
    else:
        payroll.update(payroll_net_value=gross_value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you want a second opinion. You can clean up your models, there are many redundant fields in `Payroll` such as `payroll_gross_value` is the same as the method `get_gross_value_based_on_hours`. An option is to use a model [property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#model-methods).

Also, you are also unnecessarily overriding the save method with redundant conditions by replacing the field with itself. Lastly, you can also rename your models fields to improve code readability.

models.py

```
PERCENTAGE_VALIDATOR = [MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)]

class Taxes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    percentage = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, 
        decimal_places=2, 
        validators=PERCENTAGE_VALIDATOR
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tax'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Taxes'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.percentage}%'

class FixedCosts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, 
        decimal_places=2, 
        blank=True, 
        null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Fixed Cost'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Fixed Costs'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.value} €'
    
class Payroll(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    hourly_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    worked_hours = models.IntegerField()
    taxes = models.ManyToManyField(Taxes, blank=True, related_name="payroll_taxes")
    fixed_costs = models.ManyToManyField(FixedCosts, blank=True, related_name="payroll_fixed_costs")
    send = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    send_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Payroll for {self.user.username}'

    @property
    def gross_value(self):
        return self.hourly_rate * self.worked_hours
    
    @property
    def net_value(self):
        taxes = self.taxes.all()
        fixed_costs = self.fixed_costs.all()
        net_value = self.gross_value
        
        for tax in taxes:
            net_value -= (self.gross_value * tax.percentage) / 100

        for cost in fixed_costs:
            net_value -= cost.value
        
        return net_value
```

tests.py (A simple test case)

```
class PayrollTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='test', password='test123')
        self.payroll = Payroll.objects.create(
            user=self.user, 
            date=datetime.datetime.now(), 
            worked_hours=160, 
            hourly_rate=decimal.Decimal(10)
        )

    def test_payroll_net_value_property(self):
        fixed_cost1 = FixedCosts.objects.create(
            name='Fixed Cost One', 
            value=decimal.Decimal(100)
        )
        fixed_cost2 = FixedCosts.objects.create(
            name='Fixed Cost Two', 
            value=decimal.Decimal(50)
        )

        tax1 = Taxes.objects.create(name='Tax One', percentage=10)
        tax2 = Taxes.objects.create(name='Tax Two', percentage=20)

        self.payroll.fixed_costs.add(fixed_cost1)
        self.payroll.fixed_costs.add(fixed_cost2)
        self.payroll.taxes.add(tax1)
        self.payroll.taxes.add(tax2)

        self.assertEqual(self.payroll.net_value, 970)
    
    def test_payroll_gross_value(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.payroll.gross_value, 1600)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own,

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Payroll.payroll_taxes.through)
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Payroll.payroll_fixed_costs.through)
def calculate_net_value(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    gross_value = instance.payroll_gross_value
    taxes_total = instance.payroll_taxes.all().aggregate(Sum('tax_percentage'))['tax_percentage__sum'] or 0
    taxes_total = Decimal(taxes_total / 100)
    fixed_costs_total = instance.payroll_fixed_costs.all().aggregate(Sum('value'))['value__sum'] or 0
    instance.payroll_net_value = gross_value - (gross_value * taxes_total)\
                         - fixed_costs_total
    instance.save()
```